# Does sp_recompile do anything more than ALTER PROCEDURE when recompiling a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, when there's a sudden weird performance issue with a stored procedure the first thing I try is scripting it as `ALTER PROCEDURE` then running the script, to blow away the execution plan and recompile it. Someone at work says I should use `sp_recompile` instead.

Does `sp_recompile` do anything that `ALTER PROCEDURE` doesn't, as far as recompiling a stored procedure?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618061/what-does-it-mean-to-recompile-a-stored-procedure-on-a-sql-server) answer your question

Comment: Unlike `ALTER PROC` using `sp_recompile` doesn't modify the metadata of the stored procedure, it just vacates any existing plans for it from the procedure cache. Whether or not the procedure metadata needs to be preserved is up to you.

Comment: @Squirrel: Thanks but it doesn't really answer my question.  I saw that before I posted my question.  I noticed one of the answers said `ALTER PROC` also performs a recompile, which is what I've always understood.  However, I was wondering whether `sp_recompile` does anything different from `ALTER PROC`, if `ALTER PROC` is run without changing the stored proc in any way.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Does `ALTER PROC` update anything other than the modify_date in `sys.procedures`?

Comment: Why not run a trace and do those operations to see what actually happens

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: If you'd like to turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried OPTION (RECOMPILE) in your SP to stop it caching an execution plan? Normally you shouldn't need this but occasionally SQL Server caches a plan that's good for your first execution context, but not subsequent ones. Take a look at this article-

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/12/31/sql-server-parameter-sniffing-and-option-recompile/

Comment: Thanks, that was an interesting series of articles.  I don't want to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, however, as I don't want to recompile the stored procedure every time I call it.  The performance issues we see which cause us to do a recompile only happen every 3-6 months.  And the load on the database is such that we don't want the stored procedures taking extra time to recompile every time they're called.